# PHP is_null() and ==null

Tags: php, null

In PHP, what is the difference between `is_null` and `==null` in PHP? What are the qualifications for both to return true?

Comment: This is not a duplicate - the other question asks about "===", not "=="

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`is_null` is the same as `=== null`.  Both return true when a variable is `null` (or unset).

Note that I'm using `===` and not `==`.  `===` compares type as well as value.

Comment: If the variable isn't set, `is_null()` returns `true` but also throws a "notice: undefined variable" error. To avoid this, you can do `!isset($var)` which is equivalent, the only drawback is that you can pass only variables to `isset()`.

Comment: @Rocket, When you say "is the same", do you mean **identical** also in terms of the errors and warnings that they will generate?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yep!  See this example: https://eval.in/297496

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I mean in Zend and HHVM. Basically, what I mean is, are they treated as **synonyms** in PHP?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, Yea, we need [more than just output tests.](http://3v4l.org/sTPoO) We need authoritative reference to answer that question.

Comment: @Pacerier that's something that can be easily elicited by reading the source code, if you need to know the exact implementation of `isset($undefined)` vs `is_null($undefined)`. If it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it discussed the difference between `==` and `===`, since OP asked about `==`. See Daniel Ribeiro's answer for some test cases that help show the difference. Also see dleiftah's answer for link to charts that demonstrate the difference thoroughly.

Answer (score 68):

So you can understand it better:

```
$a = null;
$b = 0;

is_null($a) // TRUE
$a == null  // TRUE
$a === null // TRUE
is_null($b) // FALSE
$b == null  // TRUE
$b === null // FALSE
```

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple really good charts on the php.net site that show how different values react:

[Type Comparison - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the comparison between **is_null()** and **null === $var**

[Good comparison between two](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/php-is_null-vs-null/)

Comment: FYI, to be clear, that is a chart comparing PERFORMANCE; I followed the link to see if there was some subtle situation where they are SEMANTICALLY different, but that is not what it is about.

Answer (score 5):

`===null` is recommended by Rasmus Lerdorf, the inventor of PHP. 
Rasmus says the test for null is faster than the test of `isset`. His recommendation is sufficient reason to look at the difference seriously. The difference would be significant if you had a small loop going through the same code thousands of times in the one Web page request.

UPD: Some speed test for is_null and strict comparison:

```
PHP 5.5.9
is_null - float(2.2381200790405)
===     - float(1.0024659633636)

PHP 7.0.0-dev
is_null - float(1.4121870994568)
===     - float(1.4577329158783)
```

Comment: When you say that someone says something, link or [citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285).

Comment: FWIW, this is not what is being asked by OP. `isset` has a different meaning.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Theme about returned value was described in best answer (marker) very well. This is addition about difference in speed

Comment: @AkimKelar - I'm pointing out that your answer is about the difference in speed between **`isset`** and `===null` - which doesn't help in deciding whether to use `is_null` or `===null`, the topic of this question.  (In case someone comes along and doesn't read carefully!)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve isn't it obvious that any non-strict comparison methods (especially methods) won't be faster than strict, is it? If no I add some speed test to answer

Answer (score 4):

`==` doesn't check the type, so somehow, somewhere, something like the string `''` or the string `'null'` may come up as equal to null.

Use triple equals sign, `===`, to not only check two values are equal but also that they are of the same type.